# Sublime Text 2 работа с потоками

Tags: c, c++, sublime-text

Доброго времени суток.
Начал использовать вышеуказанный редактор для написания лаб по C++, столкнулся с проблемой.
Допустим, компилирую программу

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a,b;
    cout<<"Введите a,b"<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<a+b<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

И вот тут возникает проблема. Ctrl+B, затем Ctrl+Shift+B (Build & Run). Программа компилируется, запускается сама откуда-то значения берет, считает и закрывается. 
Вопрос: как заставить sublime text консоль давать мне самому вводить значения? Т.е. заставить его работать с потоком ввода.

Comment: Ыыыыы. Вы уверены, что это вопрос на наш форум?

Comment: Кто разобрался, напишите код Build system под винду!

Comment: помоги, напиши на винду... у меня не получается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

смотря под какую ось.
Если под Линуск, то создайте свою "build system" `Tools->Build System->New Build System`. Содержимое можно честно скопировать с `C++.sublime-build` (который находится в `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/C++`. Вот пример переделанного

```
{
  "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
  "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
  "working_dir": "${file_path}",
  "selector": "source.c, source.c++",

  "variants":
  [
    {
      "name": "Run",
      "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "g++ '${file}' -o '${file_path}/${file_base_name}' && 'gnome-terminal -e ${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"]
    }
  ]
}
```

добавка здесь одна - `gnome-terminal -e`, которая заставит программу запуститься в отдельном терминале. Если Вам нравится другой терминал - просто укажите его, большинство терминалов  в Линуксе понимают параметр `-e`. (к примеру `xterm`).

Для Windows будет аналогично, только нужно подсмотреть правильные параметры для запуска и заменить `gnome-terminal` на `cmd`

Comment: Спасибо.
А заставить понимать ввод консоль St2 нельзя?
+ у вас маленькая ошибка. Не там кавычка стоит 
gnome-terminal -e '${file_path}/${file_base_name}'"

Comment: То есть, без открытия дополнительного терминала? Думаю, что нет. Но ведь никто не мешает перенаправить ввод.

Но иногда для мелких лабораторных куда полезнее может оказаться сайт типа [http://liveworkspace.org/](http://liveworkspace.org/). Там и ввод можно перенаправить.